# Connection to Synology AD server succeeds under iOS but fails under iPadOS

Tags: ipad, network, ipados, nas, domain

I have set up a Synology NAS as an AD server and have successfully connected a Macbook, 2 Windows PCs and an Ubuntu PC to the domain.  I don‘t know of any way to include iPads in the domain, but it is enough for me if the iPads can access the server‘s shared directories. I have succeeded in doing this with an iPad running iOS 17, but my iPad Pro running iPadOS 17 refuses to connect. If I use the NETBIOS format, <DOMAIN\username>, I get „The operation couldn‘t be completed. Invalid argument.“. If I use the email address which is registered for the user in AD, I get „You entered an invalid username or password for the server. Authentication error.“, even if I use the same account I used to successfully connect the iPad running iOS.  Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: P.S. Connection also fails in iPadOS Files when I use a local NAS account instead of a domain account.  Min. SMB version on the NAS is 2, max. version is 3.